# How to exclude files in Wix toolset

Tags: wix, heat

While harvesting files for heat.exe, I would like to exclude the files with the extension .exe from the input folder since it fetches all the files in the folder at first place.

Below is my code.

```
    %WIX_PATH%\Heat.exe" dir "%input_folder%" -cg SourceProjectComponents 
    -dr INSTALLLOCATION -scom -sreg -srd -var var.BasePath -gg -sfrag 
    -var var.BasePath -out "%output_folder%\Output.wxs
```

PS: the input_folder consists of severall .dll and .exe files. hence individual harvesting of the file wasn't possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You will need to use an XSLT transform.

Something like this should work for you; Just include `-t <Path to the xslt file>` in your command line for heat.

This XSLT outputs a new XML file that contains all XML nodes of the input, except if any nodes are `<Component>` elements with `.exe` `<File>` elements.

#### RemoveExeComponentsTransform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"

    version="1.0" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wix"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!--
    Find all <Component> elements with <File> elements with Source="" attributes ending in ".exe" and tag it with the "ExeToRemove" key.

    <Component Id="cmpSYYKP6B1M7WSD5KLEQ7PZW4YLOPYG61L" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="*">
        <File Id="filKUS7ZRMJ0AOKDU6ATYY6IRUSR2ECPDFO" KeyPath="yes" Source="!(wix.StagingAreaPath)\ProofOfPEqualsNP.exe" />
    </Component>

    Because WiX's Heat.exe only supports XSLT 1.0 and not XSLT 2.0 we cannot use `ends-with( haystack, needle )` (e.g. `ends-with( wix:File/@Source, '.exe' )`...
    ...but we can use this longer `substring` expression instead (see https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5609 )
    -->
    <xsl:key
        name="ExeToRemove"
        match="wix:Component[ substring( wix:File/@Source, string-length( wix:File/@Source ) - 3 ) = '.exe' ]"
        use="@Id"
    /> <!-- Get the last 4 characters of a string using `substring( s, len(s) - 3 )`, it uses -3 and not -4 because XSLT uses 1-based indexes, not 0-based indexes. -->

    <!-- We can also remove .pdb files too, for example: -->
    <xsl:key
        name="PdbToRemove"
        match="wix:Component[ substring( wix:File/@Source, string-length( wix:File/@Source ) - 3 ) = '.pdb' ]"
        use="@Id"
    />

    <!-- By default, copy all elements and nodes into the output... -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ...but if the element has the "ExeToRemove" key then don't render anything (i.e. removing it from the output) -->
    <xsl:template match="*[ self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef ][ key( 'ExeToRemove', @Id ) ]" />

    <xsl:template match="*[ self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef ][ key( 'PdbToRemove', @Id ) ]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This approach for filtering using xlst transforms is so hard and unintuitive that it's crying for [Cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: I edited this answer to use an XSLT 1.0 `ends-with`-style match instead of using `contains(..., '.exe')` because otherwise `app.config` files (e.g. `Foo.Bar.exe.config`) will be removed, which probably not what you want as this will cause binding-redirects to be dropped, for example (which happened to me and took ages to figure out why!)

Answer (score 11):

If you’re using WiX toolset 4.0:

The xsl filters won't work until you set the correct namespace (`xmlns:wix="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"`)
I've been in the situation of upgrading from 3.11 to 4.0 and it took me hours to find out why the filter simply didn't work. Either in VS solution nor in command line (heat.exe) version.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been really frustrated by this for the past hour and it turns out this was the issue. Maddening, just like everything else about WiX.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue where I had lots of files that I needed to include into the WXS file in a project and I wrote an open source command line application to generate XMLs of directory structure, files and components while ignoring folders, extensions, files etc via a .wixignore file (formatted similar to .gitignore).

You can take a look at the it [here](https://github.com/aykanatm/WixXmlGenerator).

Comment: @Michal Hainc, because, in my opinion, heat.exe is not very user friendly.

Comment: Just like all of Wix.  I'm still yet to understand what it does that isn't a hundred times easier to do by simply writing a program.

Answer (score 5):

I like WiX, but `heat.exe` is an utility harder to use than to make. You can write your own replacement. You just have to enumerate files in a directory, then output some XML. Here is some code to start which skip .pdb files:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryName))
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file) ?? "";
    if (extension.Equals(".pdb", OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;
    string relativePath = GetRelativePath(wixProjectDirectoryName, file);
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D").ToUpperInvariant();
    stringBuilder.AppendLine($"<Component Id=\"Comp{fileName}\" Guid=\"{guid}\">");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine($"  <File Source=\"{relativePath}\" />");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("</Component>");
}

public static string GetRelativePath(string baseDirectoryName, string fileFullPath)
{
    string[] absDirs = baseDirectoryName.Split('\\');
    string[] relDirs = fileFullPath.Split('\\');

    int len = absDirs.Length < relDirs.Length
        ? absDirs.Length
        : relDirs.Length;

    int lastCommonRoot = -1;
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < len; index++)
    {
        if (absDirs[index] == relDirs[index]) lastCommonRoot = index;
        else break;
    }

    if (lastCommonRoot == -1)
        throw new ArgumentException("No common base");

    var relativePath = new StringBuilder();

    for (index = lastCommonRoot + 1; index < absDirs.Length; index++)
    {
        if (absDirs[index].Length > 0) relativePath.Append("..\\");
    }

    for (index = lastCommonRoot + 1; index < relDirs.Length - 1; index++)
        relativePath.Append(relDirs[index] + "\\");
    
    relativePath.Append(relDirs[relDirs.Length - 1]);

    return relativePath.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i like this answer, and its what i eventually went with as xsl has some big learning curve/limitations i ran into as a beginner.
it would be even more helpful with a link to how to include c# custom actions in wix. like this one!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project

Comment: or if you wanted to use this before the installers are built, you can include it in your wixproj file like so
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835233/configure-wix-to-automatically-set-product-version-attribute

Answer (score 5):

This may be blazingly obvious, but the easiest way to do this is to use the pre-build event in wix to create a directory with only the files that you do want, then run heat.exe on that.

Comment: Yes. After seeing all the other suggestions this is the simplest and most straight forward solution.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. With all the more complicated solutions  I didn't even consider this.