# How to properly remove an Office/Outlook add-in coded with VSTO?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to write a WiX MSI installer for my Outlook add-in, that is written using Visual Studio and VSTO.

I can see that my MSI can successfully remove the following registry key upon uninstallation from Control Panel:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\{add-in-name}
```

and can also remove the add-in files from the `ProgramFiles` folder.

But when I then start up Outlook, the menu item from the add-in is still there, but being totally empty:

[image]

So how do I remove that menu item as well?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom action where you can remove your command bars' customizations. Read more about that on the following pages:

- [Adding a Custom Action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html)
- [How to create custom actions in c# and bind it on a wix setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project)

Basically, in the custom action, you need to automate Outlook and remove your command bar controls programmatically.

Comment: Oh wow. It's not that easy, I need to check that. Thanks.