# How to Update assembly in GAC folder using WiX

Tags: wix, .net-assembly, gac

Code snip:

```
      <Component Id ="zyx" Guid="{4820d7d5-30a0-448c-a80e-83609c92f235}">
        <File Id="DLLGAC" Assembly=".net" KeyPath="yes" Source="folder\pqr.xyz.dll"/>
      </Component>
```

I'm trying to upgrade older version of assembly using above code but getting error

```
skipping installation of assembly component: {4820d7d5-30a0-448c-a80e-83609c92f235} since the assembly already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience version of your library **must** be higher than installed library. And there's no option to copy with overwrite. So if library is yours - change version of library to higher.

If not:
In my case someone added to installer modified 3rd party with some higher version and it was impossible to replace it with official new version. Only way to solve it was custom action with simple `File.Copy` with overwrite.

[How to create custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144994/how-to-create-custom-actions-in-c-sharp-and-bind-it-on-a-wix-setup-project)

Comment: Version number is higher then already installed but still facing the issue

Comment: Bad. Unfortunately, sometimes wix works strange (or only legends can get how it should work)). But you still can use custom actions. As for me - it's easier to control everything from c# code.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <Component Id="zyx" Guid="{BB23E1A4-9270-41AA-9266-4D15506E1C63}" Win64="yes">
        <File Id="DLLGAC" Source="folder\pqr.xyz.dlll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"/>
      </Component>
```

After changing the code format it's working which is strange but it works :)